# Is it possible to convert an `if` statement into a `switch` statement?

Tags: java

Is it possible to convert an `if` statement into a `switch` statement in java?

Comment: Confused, do you mean are the two statements interchangeable?

Comment: You can turn an `if` statement into a 100 page thesis on the importance of bacon if you want. :) Just hit the `delete` key and start typing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, it's technically a switch **block**. Second of all, yes it is possible, but extremely unnecessary. However, if you want to do it, here is one way you could make the conversion...

```
int theCase;
if (someVariable.equals(someString)) {
    theCase = 1;
} else if (someVariable.equals(someOtherString)) {
    theCase = 2;
} else {
    theCase = 3;
}
switch (theCase) {
    case 1:
        //some code here
        break;
    case 2:
        //some code here
        break;
    case 3:
        //some code here
        break;
}
```

Of course, if you are comparing something other than strings you would use the `==` operator.

The two are also interchangeable, but only if you're working with `chars` or `ints` and only one condition is being tested.

Comment: $5 says this answer will get accepted... (look at all of Tony's questions; all the accepted answers are mine :|)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what is being evaluated in the `if` and how many of such related `if` statements you have.

If you have

```
if (i == 1)
{
    function1 (i)
}
else
if (i == 2)
{
    function2 (i)
}

if (i == 3)
{
    function3 (i)
}
```

then yes.

```
switch (i) {
    case 1:
        function1(i);
        break;
    case 2:
        function2(i);
        break;
    case 3:
        function3(i);
        break;
}
```

If you had multiple evaluations, then it becomes harder. `if (i == 1) && (j == 2)` will be much harder to represent in a switch-case block.

Answer (score 1):

I would not convert a single if statement into a switch statement, however it can be done. You will need to specify a default for the switch. If you are using many if...else statements that would warrant the switch.

```
int month = 8;
String monthString = "";
if(month == 1)
{
   monthString= "January";
}else if(month == 2)
{
  monthString= "February";
}else if(month== 3)
{
  monthString= "March";
}
etc....
```

Could be wrote like:

```
int month = 8;
String monthString;
switch (month) {
    case 1:  monthString = "January";       break;
    case 2:  monthString = "February";      break;
    case 3:  monthString = "March";         break;
    case 4:  monthString = "April";         break;
    case 5:  monthString = "May";           break;
    case 6:  monthString = "June";          break;
    case 7:  monthString = "July";          break;
    case 8:  monthString = "August";        break;
    case 9:  monthString = "September";     break;
    case 10: monthString = "October";       break;
    case 11: monthString = "November";      break;
    case 12: monthString = "December";      break;
    default: monthString = "Invalid month"; break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this example on oracles website, yes. Yes you can. Here's the link

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

It just depends on how much typing you want to do. You can have a switch statement that only has one condition, or if statements that handle multiple conditions.

Answer (score 0):

In theory sure, but they are intended to check different things.  An `if` statement is meant to respond to a particular boolean condition whereas a `switch` statement is meant to respond to a number of different possibilities.  That said, you could easily rewrite a `switch` statement as a series of `if else` statements or vice versa.  Typically though you really wouldn't want to do that.  Use a hammer to drive nails and use a screw driver to drive screws.  You could use either tool for either fastening device, they just don't work as well.